# Can I access the Google Play Music MIDI voices?

Tags: android, google-play-services, midi, midi-instrument

The Google Play Music app that came pre-installed on my Android phone can play MIDI files, meaning that it has a library of MIDI voices it can access and use.

Are these voices part of the app specifically, or part of the Android OS code? If I am creating an app that creates MIDI data, is there a way I can access these voices in order to create and play notes from within the same app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android includes the [SONiVOX Embedded Audio Synthesizer](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/jet/jetcreator_manual), which is not directly accessible from apps, except through the [JetPlayer class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/JetPlayer).

However, the synth is [open source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/sonivox/), so it would be possible to [compile the native library into your app](https://github.com/billthefarmer/mididriver).

Comment: Thanks, I thought as much but figured it was worth asking incase there was a way to access them.

As far as I can tell JetPlayer seems to be outdated or not widely used at the moment as you have to install an older version of Python to use it (please correct me if I'm wrong here) 

But I will definitely look into the source code and see if I can integrate it!

Answer (score 0):

I doubt your app can integrate the midi in The Google Play Music. I don’t know where it come from but due to security reason, you can not do so.